# Store information from .txt file using list/array

Tags: c#, .net

i can't get my head around this problem, i basically need some sort of list/array to store an ID, Name and multiple meetings during a period of 30 days foward.

So i have a txt file with employee Ids, names and booked meetings, an excerpt from the file can look like this:

```
170378154979885419149243073079764064027;Colin Gomez
170378154979885419149243073079764064027;5/17/2020 10:30:00 AM;5/17/2020 11:00:00 AM;
170378154979885419149243073079764064027;5/18/2020 7:30:00 AM;5/18/2020 10:00:00 AM;
139016136604805407078985976850150049467;Minnie Callahan
139016136604805407078985976850150049467;5/19/2014 10:30:00 AM;5/19/2020 1:00:00 PM;
```

So the first row contains a employeeId and a name of that employee.
Second line contains the employeeId, time and date of a particular meeting.

In the program i need to store this information in some form of schedule. The problem i have is that one employeer can have multiple meetings booked and i'm having trouble stooring all these meetings.
There are slots of 30minutes, meaning you can only have booked meetings starting either ??.00 or ??.30 so there should only be 48 slots available each day.
If the the employee have a booked meeting on one or several slots these slots should be marked as unavailable, a simple int that shows 1 if booked and 0 if not booked should do it.

The goal is that the schedule should show times when the employee is available for meetings one month ahead.

```
    var textFile = "C:\\textFile.txt";
    var allLinesIntextFile = File.ReadAllLines(textFile );

    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    foreach (var line in allLinesIntextFile)
    {
        if(line.Length < 60 && line.Length > 1)
        {
            int index = line.IndexOf(';');

            if(line.Substring(index).Length > 1)
            {
                var employeeId = line.Substring(0, index);
                var employeeName = line.Substring(index);

                employees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeId = employeeId, EmployeeName = employeeName });
            }


        }

    }

public class Employee
    {
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }
```

As of now i'm storing the EmployeeId and EmployeeName in a list, this is how far i'm able to get.

Sorry for my bad english, hope you understand my problem anyway! :(

Comment: Why not using a Json format instead of a CSV? If CSVis mandatory is an other separator for properties an option? Is optional column an option? Why not one CSV per person?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly. You will need to put a new List inside your employee class to store different meetings. You could make a `List<string>` and store your timestamp `5/17/2020 10:30:00 AM;5/17/2020 11:00:00 AM;` or alternatively make a `List<int>` to store your timestamp as a UNIX parsed timestamp.